# Why do we use different loss functions for classification?

Tags: classification, loss-functions

For classification problems, I wonder why using different kinds of loss functions makes sense. In particular, it feels like the model being learned, $p(y|X)$, can always be thought of as a binomial or multinomial distribution. Consequently, we can always minimize cross-entropy, as it is equivalent to the maximum likelihood for binomial or multinomial distribution.

Yet I do see that other forms of loss functions appear to be more effective than cross-entropy. For example, [polyloss](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.12511) claims to outperform cross entropy and focal loss on a variety of classification tasks.

My question is then why not always use cross entropy?  Why can a different loss sometimes do better?

Comment: Outperform in terms of what? Classification accuracy? ROCAUC? Polyloss itself?

Comment: I think there  is a misunderstanding on why Polyloss is "good". It allows having a unified view of different loss functions by tuning its hyperparameters. It's like saying Minkowski distance is better than Euclidean distance, sure, it can be better suited in certain cases if our data points do not occupy a Euclidean space.

Comment: @Dave, in terms of accuracy for ImageNet, precision/recall for COCO segmentation/detection.

Comment: @usεr11852, my question is more basis than why polyloss is good. I am asking why not always use cross entropy since it corresponds to MLE of the multinomial distribution since the goal seems to learn $P(y|X)$. We can then assign different values to false positives/negatives, etc., but that seems a second step where we choose an action that maximizes the expected utility given the learned $P(y|X)$ and our use-case specific utility function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple situations where you may not want to use cross-entropy,

1. Class imbalance: In situations where the number of samples in different classes is imbalanced, cross-entropy may not perform well. This is because cross-entropy puts more emphasis on correctly classifying the majority class, which can lead to poor performance on the minority class. In such cases, loss functions like focal loss or class-balanced loss can be more effective as they help to address this issue.
2. Addressing the model's limitations: Different loss functions can encourage the model to focus on different aspects of the data that are important for the task. For example, polyloss tries to address the limitations of softmax by encouraging the model to focus on the hardest examples in the dataset. This can help to improve the model's performance on difficult examples, which may not be well-addressed by cross-entropy.

Comment: In what way does cross-entropy loss lead to poor performance when the classes are imbalanced? This seems to go against a lot of statistical theory and posts on Cross Validated by knowledgeable people like Stephan Kolassa and Frank Harrell.